a data object that can have a "suspended" state
In a software method and system, there is a data object which has two main states: "started/pending" and "completed".
The specifications also mention an optional third state: "suspended".
When the data object is "suspended", which happens after it has been "started" of course, it cannot be moved into a "completed" state until the "suspended" state is removed, thereby returning the data object to "started/pending".
Questions:

Given the definition of the "suspended" state as it is described above, are there any more details needed to enable someone skilled in the art to implement?
If The specifications were to give an example, such as saving a key-value pair with the data object: { suspended: true }, would having this example limit the scope to this example?


Since you mention enablement, I don't think any of this is needed for enablement at all. A person of ordinary skill in the art is usually capable of designing a state machine with a "suspended" state and figuring out an appropriate persistence respresentation for it. It should be sufficient to clearly specify the set of conditions that result in entering and leaving the suspended state.

what about the second question?

Well ... you didn't post the claim itself, which is kind of required to build an opinion on it's possible scope.

the dependent claim simply adds the "suspended" state as an additional possible state.

@bhuff36 actually, it's a provisional application, we are not considering the dependent claims yet. Since the specifications cannot be modified, we have to get that right.

It’s not possible to give a yes or no answer without studying everything in the way your patent attorney presentable has.
In addition to the enablement requirement there is the “written description” requirement. It has grown from something that was rarely an issue to a nuanced issue that can trip you up.
From a leading patent law blog -

Perhaps the key to understanding the difference between enablement and the written description requirement is that you can bootstrap knowledge of one of skill in the art into your application for enablement purposes, but no such bootstrapping is allowable under the written description requirement.  If you leave something out it is not a part of your written description even if someone of skill in the art would understand that you left something out.

